# What is the iTunes's working principle for choosing picture for the artists?

Tags: itunes

I know, with adding a star by album is one solution for changing the picture, but for me that star is annoying. I had change the modification date and creation date by mp3 files, but it didn't help. So, how can I change to my choosen picture?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! It's not clear to me exactly what you're asking; can you edit your question to clarify?

Comment: Thanks! By artists on the left panel, you have a pictures from an album. For exemple, hear is a picture: http://joshhighland.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/Screen-Shot-2012-12-05-at-11.21.15-PM.png How can I change the artist picture (on left panel, the little picture) for a "novella of uriel" instead of "I dwell on thoughts of you".

Comment: Okay, I understand what you're asking now. Would you like to edit your question yourself or have me do it for you?

Comment: What version of OS X and iTunes?

Comment: Timothy, sure, you can edit it, if you have some better tittle for the thread, or just if it's gramatically something wrong...whatever. OSX is 10.10.1 and the iTunes is 12.1 version.